# Loading a passphrase-protected private SSH key from a file with the cryptography Python module

Tags: python, openssh, pem

I am trying to load a passphrase-protected private SSH key from a file using the cryptography Python module. However, I'm not exactly sure how to proceed. The following yields a `Crypto.Util.Padding.PaddingError: Padding is incorrect.` error.

```
def importPrivateKey(private_key,passphrase):
  """
  Imports the private key in an RSA object and generates the hash.
  """

  # -- Test with pgcrypto (now deprecated) -- WORKS
  with open(private_key, 'r') as private_key_file:
    key = RSA.importKey(private_key_file.read(),passphrase=passphrase)

  print(key)

  # -- Test with cryptography (active) -- FAILS
  with open(private_key,'r') as private_key_file:
    key = load_pem_private_key(private_key_file.read(),password=passphrase,backend=RSABackend())

  print(key)
  SecureString.clearmem(passphrase)

  return key
```

You can see from the snippet that I have working solution using the pycrypto module, but this module has not been updated in 5 years now. The code that uses cryptography fails with the aforementioned error.

I know there is `load_public_ssh_key` deserialization function, but this seems to operate on decrypted keys, hence my choice of `load_pem_private_key`.

Is it possible to load both private/public keys with the cryptography module?

Comment: This is indeed an interesting Q/A pair, but IMHO it would be more on topic on SO.

Comment: This question is now too old to migrate. If you want to delete it, you would have to delete the answer first.

Answer (score 2):

Like any beginner, I made this more complicated that it needed to be, and didn't read the documentation properly.

The key must be read as bytes (`'rb'`), and the passphrase must also be bytes-like, as per the [documentation](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/backends/interfaces/?highlight=load_pem_private_key#cryptography.hazmat.backends.interfaces.PEMSerializationBackend.load_pem_private_key).

```
import SecretString
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization import load_ssh_public_key, load_pem_private_key
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization import Encoding
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization import PublicFormat

def importPrivateKey(private_key,passphrase):
  """
  Imports the private key in an RSA object and generates the hash.
  """
  with open(private_key,'rb') as private_key_file:
    key = load_pem_private_key(private_key_file.read(),
                               password=passphrase.encode(),
                               backend=default_backend())

  public_key = key.public_key()

  print(public_key.public_bytes(Encoding.OpenSSH,PublicFormat.OpenSSH))
  SecureString.clearmem(passphrase)

  return key
```